# Calls Dropping, Phone Line Missing, Caller ID Not Functional on Cisco 2811 CME

Tags: cisco, router, cisco-7900-ip-phones

The Cisco 2811 at work employs approximately 10~12 phones.

None of the phones are displaying caller id though every line is configured for it.

```
voice-port 0/0/0
 connection plar opx 2000
 caller-id enable
!
voice-port 0/0/1
 connection plar opx 2000
 caller-id enable
!
voice-port 0/0/2
 connection plar opx 2000
 caller-id enable
!
voice-port 0/0/3
 connection plar opx 2000
 caller-id enable
```

Everyone is also experiencing dropped calls, where the line will immediately terminate.

This isn't a live `show config` of the router. It's a previous config that was taken when everything was functional. I'll double check the config in the morning but does anyone have any idea why this would begin to happen out of the blue? The router is on a backup power supply but even if it did restart shouldn't it load from the `startup-config` which I copied from the running config.

Comment: Where are the calls originating and where are the calls terminating?  Have you checked the cpu and memory on the router?  Are the phones directly attached to the router or do they go through a switch?  Were there any changes made around the time this problem started?

Comment: And yes, when the router boots up, it will load the startup config into memory where it becomes the running config.

Comment: @AveryAbbott the dropped calls are originating from all over and it does not matter to which phones they terminate, it is indiscriminate.  
The phones are directly attached to the router and do not go through a switch.  There were no changes made to the routers config around the time this problem started.  It was noted however that the service provider was seen working on the comms box down the road, if this makes any difference at all.  How can I check the CPU and mem on the router?

Comment: @AveryAbbott the CPU and memory look fine.  
  
Processor Pool Total:  149663776 Used:   44106780 Free:  105556996  
  
I/O Pool Total:   14680064 Used:    6650000 Free:    8030064  

CPU utilization for five seconds: 8%/0%; one minute: 7%; five minutes: 7%

Comment: Are there any redundant links in your network that might have been flapping?  Are you using any port channels anywhere between the router and the phones?

Comment: @AveryAbbott I restarted the router and that did the trick.

Comment: @AveryAbbott I'm continuing to have dropped call issues. I was wrong about my earlier statement in which the phones do not go through ha switch. They do and go through a 2950.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting the router resolved the issue.